# PyDev content assist: 'The interpreter location found does not exist.'

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm slowly getting more productive with Python, and would like to move from Spyder to PyDev. I can run my code fine, but the content assist ([ctrl]+[space]) feature of Eclipse isn't working -- any ideas?

When I run the code ([ctrl]+[F11]), it executes fine, and when I open an interactive terminal ([alt]+[ctrl]+[enter], choose Python console), the suggestions I expect come up (though [ctrl]+[space] still gives this error).

The full error given in the tooltip is:

```
    The interpreter location found does not exist. <xml>
    <name>Python27</name>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executable>python</executable>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\control-0.6c-py2.7.
     egg</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\DLLs</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\FontTools</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\itk</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode</lib>
    <lib>C:\Python27\python.exe</lib>
    <forced_lib>Image</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>OpenGL</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>__builtin__</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>__main__</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_ast</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_bisect</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_bytesio</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs_cn</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs_hk</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs_iso2022</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs_jp</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs_kr</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_codecs_tw</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_collections</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_csv</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_fileio</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_functools</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_heapq</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_hotshot</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_io</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_json</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_locale</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_lsprof</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_md5</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_multibytecodec</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_random</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_sha</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_sha256</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_sha512</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_sre</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_struct</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_subprocess</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_symtable</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_warnings</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_weakref</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>_winreg</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>array</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>astropy</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>astropy.units</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>audioop</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>binascii</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>cPickle</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>cStringIO</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>cmath</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>datetime</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>email</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>errno</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>exceptions</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>future_builtins</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>gc</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>hashlib</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>imageop</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>imp</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>itertools</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>marshal</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>math</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>mmap</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>msvcrt</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>nose</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>nose.tools</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>nt</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>numpy</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>operator</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>os</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>os.path</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>parser</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>pytest</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>scipy</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>signal</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>socket</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>strop</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>sys</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>thread</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>time</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>wx</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>wxPython</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>xxsubtype</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>zipimport</forced_lib>
    <forced_lib>zlib</forced_lib>
    </xml>
```

*Edit:* comment suggestion of YerayDiazDiaz:

Under PyDev -> Interpreter -> Python I had a single interpreter there, from "Quick Auto-Config". It has Name="Python" and Location="python". Libraries seem OK.

I've tried removing it, and adding an interpreter with "New", where I've set "Interpreter Name:"="System", "Interpreter Executable"="C:\Python27\python.exe". This seems to add the libraries OK, but now I can neither run my code (Error about invalid configuration, "Interpreter: python not found") nor use the code completion (tooltip error is "Interpreter: python not found").

If I have both interpreters there (the one from Quick Auto-Config, and my own "System"), then I can run the code again, but code completion fails with the original error.

I'm running Windows 7, 64 bit; Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1; PyDev version 3.2.0.201312292215

Comment: Check in your preferences, under PyDev, Interpreter - Python you should have a System interpreter. Make sure it points to the right file and the libraries are also correct.

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- couldn't get it working though. Updated question with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it seems to be working now -- I had to create a new project, and for the new project everything works as expected.

Using the "Quick Auto-Config" under "Preferences - PyDev - Interpreters - Python Interpreter" seems to be the culprit. Instead, I do "New...", click on Browse, find my python.exe, and select that. If I now create a new PyDev project, the code completion works as expected.

Comment: Can you please add that to https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev (I actually thought that this issue was already fixed, in 3.2.0, but it seems something is still not working properly there).

Comment: Hi Fabio - I am unable to log into that site -- I've tried creating a user with Google & Github (both return 403:Forbidden), and Facebook (`Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`).

Comment: Please contact me at fabioz.pydev at gmail dot com with the details you have on that then (I just tested it here and it worked, so, let's try to check what may be happening there).

Answer (score 1):

I was using Squish (with Python) for Automation of a Windows application. the code completion was having issues. During scripting when I select "Control" + "Enter", there was an error saying - *“The interpreter location found does not exist”*

**Solution is as Below:**

I followed the below steps and this solved the issue

(1) In Squish, go to “Edit” menu  -> “Preferences” (in windows platform)

(2) In “Preferences” window, Select “PyDev” -> “Interpreter – Python”

(3) Remove all the entries on the right hand side and select “Auto Config”

(4) Save and re-start Squish – the issue will be gone and context assist will be seen during scripting